# Exponential equation Exercises

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

Today I have big problem. Our teacher gave us this HW with exponential equation for marks. I do not want to get bad mark so I am here. Please help me. I did a lot. And I also know how to solve basic exponential equation problems, but not these.

$1)$ $$  4^{x+1}-768=4^x$$

$2)$ $$\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{3x-3}=\left(\frac{64}{49}\right)^{2-x}$$

$3)$ $$ 3^x-1=\frac{72}{3^x}$$

Comment: Please make your title informative, a title that describes your problem (stating that it's a homework problem is not informative).  Also, you should format your questions using MathJaX format instead of including links.  Finally, it would be very helpful if you were to provide some details of what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I have stucked everywhere :D. Especially in number 3 and number 1.

Comment: Do good exercises 1) take logarithm 2) take logarithm 3) solve quadratic assuming $3^x=t$

Comment: Yeah, there is the problem. We did not learned logarithm yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1) $ Put $y= 4^x$

$2) $ Put $y= \left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^x$

$3) $ Put $y= 3^x$ you will get a quadratic eq. of $y$

Comment: Ok so firts is equal to 4.   And the second one for me is 1 but it can not be, can it?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Without substitution and without logarithm.

$4^{x+1}- 768 = 4^x$

$\iff \frac{4^{x+1}} {4^x} - \frac {768} {4^x} = \frac {4^x} {4^x}=1$ ( Dividing by $4^x$)

$\iff 4^{[(x+1)-x]}  - \frac {768} {4^x} = 1$ ( Using $\frac {a^n} {a^m}= a^{n-m}$)

$\iff 4^{1}  - \frac {768} {4^x} = 1$

$\iff - \frac {768} {4^x} = 1 -4 = -3$

$\iff \frac {768} {4^x} = 3$ ( Multiplying both sides by $(-1)$ )

$\iff 4^x = \frac {768} {3} = 256$ ( By cross product and , then, division by $3$).

$\iff 4^x = 4^4$

$ \iff x = 4$. ( By : $(b^n = b^m) \rightarrow n=m$ ).

Answer (score 1):

For (1) we have:
$$4^{x+1}-4^x=768$$
$$4\cdot 4^x-4^x=3\cdot 256$$
$$(4-1)4^x=3\cdot 4^4$$
$$4^x=4^4$$
so
$$\color{red}{x=4}.$$

---

For (2) instead:
$$\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{3x-3}=\left[\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)^2\right]^{2-x}$$
$$\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{3x-3}=\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)^{2(2-x)}$$
$$\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{3x-3}=\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{-2(2-x)}$$
$$3x-3=-2(2-x)$$
$$3x-3=-4+2x$$
$$\color{red}{x=-1}.$$

---

Finally, (3): multiplying LHS and RHS by $3^x$ we get
$${\left(3^x\right)}^2-3^x-72=0.$$
Substituting $y=3^x$ we get
$$y^2-y-72=0.$$
$\Delta=289>0$ and $y$ is either $9$ or $-8$. Now $y=3^x=9$ gives
$$\color{red}{x=2}$$
while there is no real $x$ such that $y=3^x=-8<0$.